# Generating PEM private key file knowing n and d

Tags: python, rsa, asn.1, pem

For academic reasons I have succeeded to factor a small size RSA public key and extract n,p,q,e and then computed d. My question is, is there a way using python to generate a .pem private key file for the private key (d,n), in order to make it easy to verify the encryption/decryption goes well?

Answer (score 0):

The pyasn1 and pyasn1-modules packages together would provide you with the data structures used for storing private key information (PKCS#8). The above mentioned packages could also serialize/deserialize private key data structures what (along with base64 encoding) makes up a PEM file.

See pyasn1-modules/tools/pkcs8dump.py tool and [pyasn1 documentation](http://pyasn1.sf.net) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but [this script](https://github.com/jpf/okta-jwks-to-pem) should help you achieve your goal. Here's what the author says about it:

> ## Introduction
>
> This is a Python script that fetches JWKS results, and for each jwk,
>   uses the **modulus** and **exponent** to generate a PEM encoded public
>   key, suitable for use in tools like [jwt.io](https://jwt.io)
>
> Here is an example of using this tool to get the PEM encoded public
>   keys for the "example.okta.com" Okta org:
>
> ```
> ./jwks_to_pem.py --org example.okta.com
>
> Fetching JWKS from example.okta.com
> PEM for KID 're7eOFV6SiygSbCyYHGGdERFCJ_EoNpi9Duv0FIxllo'
> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
> MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAgVdVgO4RogxtWt4XN2vO
> 9SG3Ekt6Qh+k6Io28dTNjEWuNxCYCtQI2dFtFs2y7OyLxQ2e3491XTDVRxtUx/Kl
> RhQCcGDtLM5vTRWtGo39heg9dLWv7mqlk+jVkJrK2vAO+0bfl0x2Ouov4VS4Ixwx
> lJfaec8v0cw+xjcJc29Y28WNFYhW/wpf1uEHYAf/pQ9q7S25rhK5yPv23101P7pA
> bCNDyFB6PYLuXxqkE7dq7rIZXfw5xgNQBRugBrSmUEjoCFs3XowAXCk2gWhM/1Lg
> mSqaaAh/Cu5vvzM0wYoaEi598LWYmtgurQ3C2Nenu8HVjI+zCSg8v7VrcTa1MHua
> owIDAQAB
> -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
>
> PEM for KID 'kTP2cLZY0qA2qfnedNEgx6rs6yqIEdf4DQYYV2m4KPQ'
> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
> MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAjKb91FLaoZe9/5NEMZrO
> 1eDn4hdrhtjrvsy+qO1QIbbdhRXJIJoE+qpHmgmq1gK28OZCV51xUAwk8ugw5p7/
> m2wIarykHtXuBmhcFPkWez6N/yX30qvdOPPKUGqd05AoGcrzAW6fV07CRROU+5g1
> RnTdNasLEMYaq0xPlmCMDjb3usyiafGyyrwg4+tndOTry4uMtF7LeTVLZo9Tnn2x
> dJiytWWh+Rq5/KAn1mJ2GgwG8tp8o7SRf65c0LYQenN1d6vXX/Iimq/mg//B5CHP
> zIaUrZfoL+2sbRIyQ5AePlDyn8Neg6sIsV9nTkPAcYvvQsS+/8xnfNq6np0zKbua
> dQIDAQAB
> -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
> ```